# My CSS classes won't get recognized

Tags: html, css

I'm following a tutorial on YouTube on how to customize my checkboxes (https://youtu.be/ojWA8pdT-zY?t=5m58s) for a form but my CSS classes won't get recognized. Not sure why.

This is how I got it's referenced in HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1"/><span class="labeltext">1<span></label>
```

And this is how I got it in CSS:

```
.labeltext:before {
    content: "hello";
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I can already see in Visual Studio Code that it doesn't get recognized because the color of **.labeltext** doesn't change like it normally does.

I tried to make it an ID to see if that would resolve it, but no luck on that.

Thank you for taking your time to at least read my question!

**EDIT:** I realized the typo.. lol. But after the typo fix, it didn't fix my issue.

**EDIT2:** my entire CSS what I got so far. As suggested by a user

```
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

+.label-text:before {
  content: "hello";
}
```

**EDIT3:** solved it! the + in the CSS was interfering for some reason. Anyway, it works like I wanted to now. Thanks everyone for trying to help me!

Comment: Visual Studio Code has terrible syntax highlighting. Does it actually work in your browser? Because that looks like it should work.

Comment: sadly it doesn't work in my browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Typo**

`</span>`

```css
.labeltext:before {
  content: "hello";
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1"/><span class="labeltext">1</span></label>
```

Comment: wow I'm actually dumb as shit. But that typo fix didn't seem to fix my problem. Although it works in your snippet.

Comment: :-) Could you provide the complete CSS on jsfiddle? Something else is in the way.

Comment: ofcourse! I just added the complete CSS on jsfiddle in the post.

Comment: Use validator to check syntax and typos.

Comment: Im gonna use that from now on yeah. But it has been fixed now! Thank you for trying to help me! The + in CSS was interfering with the code

Comment: I recognized that. The man in the video is using sass and stylus. It's really irritating. There is a CSS solution in the comment: https://codepen.io/garethconnop/pen/yxcsD

Comment: oh. So that's the issue. Alright. Do I just need to copy that css bit from codepen.io and paste it into my code? Thanks by the way!

Comment: Yes, it should be the complete HTML and CSS.

Comment: Oh wow! This is great man! Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nabtron/h7ntro6x/2/

However, your code has an error, the closing span tag doesn't have a `/span` ( `/` is missing)

Comment: yeah I realized the typo and that made me wanna punch myself. But after the typo fix it didn't fix my issue :/

Comment: can you share screenshot of wht ur code is showing u

Comment: ofcourse! here is a link to a screenshot I posted through imgur: https://imgur.com/a/LhLuR